# PHP curl_multi_getcontent Always Outputs the content

Tags: php, curl, php-7, php-curl, curl-multi

I am building a site "monitor", and have decided to utilize `curl_multi_*` due to the number of sites I need to monitor as well as the multiple curl pulls I need to make per iteration.

**CODE:**

https://gitlab.com/snippets/1739288

(too much to post here, though if needed I can)

The issue that I am running into is line 82(ish), seems to always output the content of the page, rather than assigning it to the variable `$_content`, and because of this, I am not able to "search" the content for the `$_test_string` that I need to, thus it always fails.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get that content set to the variable so I can actually test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second channel setting is still using the first channel variable:

```
// first handle sepcific
curl_setopt( $_ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
// second handle specific
curl_setopt( $_ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
             ^^^^^
```

Take this moment to learn why cutting-and-pasting code is bad. If you have to write something more than once, use a function. :)

Comment: Fixed it, and works semi-perfect now ;)  It's been a long long week.  Any idea why it would now output the headers?

Comment: Because you told it to? `curl_setopt( $_ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );`